# Buying a Navigo Travel Card at Orly Airport 2022

Tags: transit

Is it still possible to buy the Navigo Travel Card (All Zones) at Orly Airport or do you have to be at an RER station? many thanks

Comment: I wonder whether you can buy one at the _Aéroport d'Orly_ T7 station on an automatic ticket machine.

Comment: There’s also the sales office of Orlyval (which is manned). But I remember the machines there explicitly not selling passes (probably to avoid confusion over the fact that Orlyval is not included), despite the machines obviously being standard RATP stuff. Don’t know if the manned sales desk will sell any Navigo cards or passes.